# How to pass scope value through route provider to controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a search field and when i click on the search button, i will make a search in data using the value entered in the search field. This is my code.

**HTML code**

```
<a href="#/home">Home</a>
<label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text"><a ng-href="#/search/{{searchVal}}" ng-model="searchVal">Search</a>
</label>
```

**JS code**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
 .controller('searchController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    var name = $routeParams.name;
    alert(name)
});

angular.module('myApp')
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
      }).
      when('/search/:name', {
        templateUrl: 'search.html',
        controller: 'searchController'
      }). 
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });
});
```

Here i cant pass the search value to the routeProvider. How to pass the search value through `routeProvider` and access that in the `searchController`.

I used `routeParams` in the controller, but i cant retrieve the value of the search field.

So, how to get the value in the searchController? This is the [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Wux9xReW8B94aVArFvo?p=preview)

Comment: Is it OK to add a index controller for the handling the `href` in the controller. Its very possible that the `<a>` is not working inside the `<input>`

Answer (score 1):

You should define the search parameter in the route definition for the routeParams to recognise the param.

```
when('/search/:name', {
    templateUrl: 'search.html?query',
    controller: 'searchController'
})
```

You can retrieve the value in the controller by using `routeParams.query`.

Answer (score 0):

You have been assigning the `ng-model` to the `<a>` rather than the `input`.

```
<a href="#/home">Home</a>
<label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchVal"><a ng-href="#/search/{{searchVal}}">Search</a>
</label>
```

Working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LWjHX5XzXINnkNBwGq42?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The only issue with your code is to associate ng-model with anchor tag instead with input tag. Because we input the value to input box and which is directly associated with ng-model.

Below is the change which have to made:

```
<a href="#/home">Home</a>
<label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchVal"><a ng-href="#/search/{{searchVal}}">Search</a>
</label>
```